# Error while Use of <exec> tag in NAnt

Tags: nant

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <project name="Project" default="build">
 <property name="program" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" />
 <property name="name.proj" value="C:\project\proj.csproj" />
 <target name="build">
   <exec program="${program}"commandline="\devenv.exe ${name.proj}"  />
 </target>
</project>
```

Its output is....

```
Error in Script usage:The Correct usage is:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" [Option], where option= x86,ia64,or x86_ia64.
```

But when i gives the x86 option ,it again comes with error.."/ is an unexpected token"

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Just an observation, but does it make a difference if you put a space between the `"${program}"` and the `commandline` attribute in your `<exec>` node?

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing:

```
<exec program="${program}" commandline="x86"  />
```

I am not sure why you are passing devenv.exe as commandline. You probably want to do that in a separate exec task

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:

```
<exec program="${program}">
    <arg value="x86" />
</exec>
```

[source](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/exec.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample EXEC for get latest from VSS

```
<target name="getlatest" >
       <property name="path.cmd.exe" value="C:\WINDOWS\system32\CMD.EXE"/>
          <property name="path.vss.bat" value="C:\Work\build\DailyBuild\nAnt\VSSGET.bat"/>

    <echo>
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TASK : GET LATEST FROM VSS
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </echo>
    <echo message="Task Start at: ${datetime::now()}" />

   <loadtasks assembly="nantcontrib-0.85/bin/NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />         

    <exec program="${path.cmd.exe}">
        <arg value="/C"  />     
        <arg value="${path.vss.bat}"  />
     </exec>
</target>
```